# implement errno analogue using pthread

Tags: c, pthreads, errno

As `$ man errno` says, "errno is defined by the ISO C standard to be a modifiable lvalue of type int, and must not be explicitly declared; errno may be a macro. errno is thread-local; setting it in one thread does not affect its value in any other thread".

I'm developing a C library which will work both in POSIX and Windows, so instead of using `errno` and `GetLastError/SetLastError` I've decided to stick to my own error type. Every my function returns error code as `cg_error` object, where `cg_error` is just a typedef. However, for some functions like custom allocators it is still better to use something like `errno`, but with my own `cg_error` type.

AFAIK errno in glibc is implemented this way:

`#define errno (*__errno_location ())`

I'm trying to implement a similar function using `pthreads` on Linux and `TlsAlloc` and friends for Windows. Here is what I have now (yet only POSIX, seems to be a Solaris implementation from article *"Thread-Specific Storage pattern"* found on the Web):

```
cg_error * CG_ERRNO_TLS(void)
{
#if CG_FEATURE_POSIX
  static int once;
  static pthread_key_t key;
  static pthread_mutex_t lock;
  cg_error * error = NULL;
  if (once)
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    if (once)
    {
      (void) pthread_key_create(&key, cg_free);
      once = 1;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
  }
  error = pthread_getspecific(key);
  if (!error)
  {
    error = cg_malloc(sizeof(*error));
    (void) pthread_setspecific(key, error);
  }
  return error;
#endif
}

#define cg_errno (*CG_ERRNO_TLS())
```

However, when I try to set or get `cg_errno`, its int value is `6344768`, which is not what I want. What am I doing wrong? What's the right way to define something like `errno`? Thanks in advance!

**P.S.** I know that I could use `__thread` and `__declspec(thread)`, but such things are compiler-specific (and probably system specific; I've heard that `__thread` doesn't work e.g. for MacOSX with gcc).

**P.P.S.** Base value of `cg_error` is `CG_ERROR_NONE`, which is always 0.

**UPDATE**:

```
#if CG_FEATURE_POSIX
static pthread_key_t cg_errno_key;
static pthread_once_t cg_errno_once = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;


static void cg_errno_init(void)
{ (void) pthread_key_create(&cg_errno_key, cg_free); }


cg_error * cg_errno_storage(void)
{
  cg_error * error = NULL;
  (void) pthread_once(&cg_errno_once, cg_errno_init);
  error = pthread_getspecific(cg_errno_key);
  if (!error)
  {
    error = cg_malloc(sizeof(*error));
    (void) pthread_setspecific(cg_errno_key, error);
  }
  return error;
}

#define cg_errno (*cg_errno_storage())
#endif
```

Comment: it does not appear that you ever initialize the once variable.    also, assuming you only want the once block to execute once, you'd need to set once to 0 after your pthread_key_create() call (which means you would want to initialize once to 1).  as it stands your once block probably doesnt get called so your pthread_setspecific() will error out (you can check this yourself by checking the return value of pthread_setspecific(), should return 0 on success)

Comment: `lock` should have an initializer, `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your condition on `once` is wrong. It should be `!once`.

But using an `int` for that is not guaranteed to work. There is a special type `pthread_once_t` with function `pthread_once` for the task that you are trying to achieve.

Also, `lock` should have an initializer, `PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER`.

A use of `pthread_once_t` would look like this:

```
static pthread_key_t key;
static pthread_once_t once = PTHREAD_ONCE_INIT;

static
void init_error_key_once(void) {
  pthread_key_create(&key, cg_free);
}

cg_error * CG_ERRNO_TLS_POSIX(void)
{
  cg_error * error = NULL;
  pthread_once(&once, init_error_key_once);
  ...

}
```

Comment: Thanks, now it works. I've added a working version; do you still see any errors? There are not so much articles about TLS, so someone may find it useful.

Comment: @ghostmansd, `pthread_once_t` is not supposed to be used like this. Put all your initialization stuff in a function and use the POSIX function `pthread_once`.

Comment: Do I need to `malloc` inside `CG_ERRNO_TLS` or inside `init_error_key_once`? I've update functions again; hope I've understood you correct.

Comment: I also suppose that `CG_ERRNO_PTR` must be destroyed when all thread exit. Am I right that providing a destructor to `pthread_key_create` already eliminates this problem?

Comment: @ghostmansd, no `static` CG_ERRNO_PTR needed, that wouldn't work, it would share the pointer across the whole process, exactly what you didn't wanted. Leave it as you had it before for that part. (Also common coding styles reserve all uppercase names for macros. Makes your code difficult to read for outsiders.)

Comment: Yet another update, according to your style suggestions and fixes.

Comment: If I now have `cg_errno`, shall it be considered a good practice to return error code from functions? If yes, is it a good idea to return code **and** set `cg_errno` simultaneously? I mean to return codes from all functions where it may be appreciable (i.e. not `malloc` and `free` analogue functions, such as constructors and destructors).

Comment: `valgrind` shows that I have a memory leak; I think that it is because `valgrind`'s check has nothing common with thread allocated resources.

Comment: valgrind should be able to track all threads that are created by your program and see the corresponding `free`. The only thread where it might not see such a thing is the one of `main`. You could add a function with `atexit` that frees that last `cg_error` and calls `pthread_key_delete`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45302/discussion-between-ghostmansd-and-jens-gustedt)